# How to display sum value of all rows as common column for all the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where  am getting data by grouping with one column. The results has 25 rows with each district id and its value. Now I want to display all the 25 rows sum value as fourth column as common value for all the 25 rows.

Please help me on this

Thanks

Comment: You have query, but why do you not show the query in your question?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `SUM()` as a window function:

```sql
SELECT id, SUM(val) AS sum, SUM(SUM(val)) OVER () AS total_sum
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id;
```